How to use the VListGroup component in Vuetify to create a navigation Item for page navigation
Originally, the VListGroup is used to create the sublist group in VList.
But also, we sometimes need to use that to perform opening the sub list and, at the same time, navigating the specific page (in a navbar).
For example, The VList used for VNavigationDrawer and every VListItem works as RouterLink with to props.
Also, VListGroup will work like that too, so when clicking the VListGroup, sub list should be dropped down and the appropriate page will be opened at the same time.
So, I've tried the following way:
<v-list-group
:value='item.title'

> 

    <template v-slot:activator='{props}'>
      <v-list-item 
        v-bind:='props' 
        :value='item.title'
        :title='item.title' 
        :to='item.to ? item.to: undefined'
        rounded
        color='secondary'
      >
... ...

However, after that, the page reloaded while navigation works, and therefore the sub list never open. In other words, the sub list never open because of the reloading. And I can't understand why the reloading happened and not works like other VListItem withto\ props.
Could you please let me know the best solution?
